What laws relate to the taking/possessing of foetuses?
The news today is an anti-abortion activist has been jailed.  This story includes the point that in 2022 police discovered five foetuses at the home where was arrested and had lived or stayed.  That story includes the statement:

"There doesn't seem to be anything criminal in nature about that except for how they got into this house," Ashan Benedict, executive assistant Washington DC police chief, said at a news conference.
Ms Handy recently claimed to have "gained access" to a foetal tissue and organ bank at the University of Washington in Seattle, but the university said nothing was taken.

If these were dead bodies a recent question here has detailed all sorts of crimes that could have occurred.  If these were actual property at a University (perhaps HeLa cells or museum specimens) it would seem that to "gain access" to and take them would be theft.
What sort of property/possession law applies to foetuses, or the remains thereof?  Is it credible that a protester could take and possess such material without committing a crime until they brought it to their dwelling?
